# how to set state with reponse ajax request in reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I bind and used this still getting this error ,did the same thing for
another it worked perfect when did the same here, But I'm getting a error.

```
 class Player extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.setState={
            video:{}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
         var sess=localStorage.getItem('sessionId');
        var id=this.props.params.vid;
```

> local ajax request console log shows my request is good

```
    $.ajax({
      method:'GET',
       url:'video',
       data:{
         'sessionId':sess,
         'videoId':id
       },
       success:function(res){
         this.setState({ video:res.data })
       }.bind(this)
    });
  }
    render(){

        return(

            <div id="videoplay">
            <div className="video-title"></div>
              <video  controls src="/images/Google_Cardboard_Assembly.mp4">
            </video>
                <div className="video-metadata">

                    <div className="video-rating"></div>
                    <div className="video-description"></div>                    

                </div>
            </div>           
        );
    }

}
```

**error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

Comment: you should handle this in the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`.

Comment: i am still getting the same error

Comment: You're setting `this.setState = { video: {} }` that's the problem.

Comment: so what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the constructor, you just need to do `this.state = { video: {} }` not `this.setState`

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        video:{}
    };
}
```

`this.setState` can be used anywhere else but the constructor. non es6 way of doing this was doing:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return { 
    video: {}
  }
}
```

which is equivalent to just doing `this.state = {}` in the constructor

Answer (score 4):

here is how i got it work

```
class Login extends Component{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state={
  email:'',
  password:''
  emailError:'',
  passwordError:''
  }
  this.userLogin=this.userLogin.bind(this);
  this.handleUserInput=this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
 }

handleUserInput(){
 const name = e.target.name;
 const value = e.target.value;
 this.setState({[name]: value})
}

userLogin(){
var body={
  email:this.state.email,
  password:this.state.password
}
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/userLogin',
  data: body,
  success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if(data==='valid'){
      window.location.href='/dashboard';
      }
      else{
      //setting error details here
      this.setState({emailError:'email doesn\'t exist', 
        passwordError:'incorrect password'});
      window.location.href='/';
      }
  }.bind(this),
  error:function(){
    console.log("error");
    this.setState({emailError:'email doesn\'t exist', 
    passwordError:'incorrect password'});
  }.bind(this)
});
}

render(){
return(
<div>
   <h2>Login:</h2>
  <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" onChange={(event) 
       => this,handleUserInput(event)}/>
     <h6>{this.state.emailError}</h6>
     <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"  onChange={(event) 
       => this,handleUserInput(event)}/>
     <h6>{this.state.passwordError}</h6>
     <button onClick={this.userlogin}>Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your constructor method from:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.setState={
        video:{}
    };
}
```

to:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        video:{}
    };
}
```

Also, I think `this` in `this.setState()` call does not refer to your Class in `$.ajax()` call. Try binding both: the `ajax()` call and the `success()` function or use the arrow function for your `success()` method.

Comment: Do you still get error that `setState` is not a function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React lifecycle methods to make your request.

#### Example

```
class YourClass extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      video: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'video',
      data: {
        sessionId: sess,
        videoId: id
      },
      success: (res) => {
        this.setState({ video:res.data })
      }
    });
  }

  render () {
    return ( /* ... your render method ... */ );
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with your exact class code, including imports and header.

Comment: Use the syntax for your `success` callback as in my example above.